# Problems with very simple GtkTextView use case

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I'm having a Gtk+ 3.0 UI designed with glade and implemented in C with two list view (implmented as GtkTreeView). When I click on one item in the second list view I want details of the entry to be displayed in a multi line text view. There is no other choice than using GtkTextView, even though I need maybe less than 1% of what GtkTextView provides (I don't even need to edit).
However, having the GtkTextView element on my UI the program crashes at the first clicks on the list. When I remove the updating of the GtkTextView from my code, I can play around eternally with the UI, no crash ever.
Here is the code which updates the text view:

```
// get stuff from list store

gtk_tree_model_get_iter (GTK_TREE_MODEL (liststore), &iter, tree_path);
gtk_tree_model_get (GTK_TREE_MODEL (liststore), &iter,
                  ITEM_NAME, &itemName,
                  ITEM_DESC, &itemDesc,
                  ITEM_LINK, &itemLink, -1);
// fill a couple of one line GtkEntry first
// ...
// fill the text view
txtBuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (txtDesc));
gtk_text_buffer_set_text (txtBuffer, itemDesc, -1);
```

I've checked that itemDesc is non-NULL. I've analyzed this with valgrind and the funny thing is that no obvious memory handling error is detected but a stack overflow! I'm nowhere using recursion... Anyway, here's the valgrind output:

```
==4879== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff8
==4879== 
==4879== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4879==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF8
==4879==    at 0x5B36564: g_hash_table_lookup (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4000.0)
==4879==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4879==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4879==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4879==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4879==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4879== 
==4879== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4879==     in use at exit: 3,946,706 bytes in 45,434 blocks
==4879==   total heap usage: 326,942 allocs, 281,508 frees, 25,249,132 bytes allocated
==4879== 
==4879== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4879==    definitely lost: 3,664 bytes in 32 blocks
==4879==    indirectly lost: 12,977 bytes in 542 blocks
==4879==      possibly lost: 165,544 bytes in 1,342 blocks
==4879==    still reachable: 3,594,265 bytes in 42,477 blocks
==4879==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4879== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4879== 
==4879== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4879== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Any idea is appreciated. Here's the C code.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

#include "kpodcast.h"
#include "global.h"

GtkBuilder *builder;

enum {
    PODCAST_NAME = 0,
    NCOLUMNS
};

enum {
    ITEM_NAME = 0,
    ITEM_DATE = 1,
    ITEM_DESC = 2,
    PODCAST_IDX = 3,
    ITEM_LINK = 4,
    NCOLUMNS2
};

extern GList        * all_podcasts;
extern GTimeZone    * gTimeZone;
extern sqlite3      * db;

void kleine_callback (GtkWidget *w, gpointer d)
{
    GtkWidget *dialog;
    dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (NULL,
    GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE, "Hallo, Welt!");
    gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
}

void
on_item_selection_change (GtkTreeSelection * widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    GList        * selection  = gtk_tree_selection_get_selected_rows (widget, NULL);
    GtkTreePath  * tree_path  = NULL;
    GtkLabel     * txtDesc    = NULL;
    GtkEntry     * txtLink    = NULL;
    GtkTextBuffer* txtBuffer  = NULL;
    GtkEntry     * txtName    = NULL;
    GtkListStore * liststore  = NULL;
    char         * message    = NULL;
    GtkTreeIter    iter;
    gchar        * itemName   = NULL;
    gchar        * itemDesc   = NULL;
    gchar        * itemLink   = NULL;
    GtkStatusbar * status_bar = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "status_bar"));

    txtName = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "txtItemName"));
    txtDesc = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "txtItemDesc"));
    txtLink = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "txtItemLink"));

    if (selection != NULL) {
        tree_path = (GtkTreePath *) selection->data;
        int depth = gtk_tree_path_get_depth (tree_path);
        int * idx = gtk_tree_path_get_indices (tree_path);
        liststore = GTK_LIST_STORE (gtk_builder_get_object (builder,  "liststore_podcast_items"));

        gtk_tree_model_get_iter (GTK_TREE_MODEL (liststore), &iter, tree_path);
        gtk_tree_model_get (GTK_TREE_MODEL (liststore), &iter,
                            ITEM_NAME, &itemName,
                            ITEM_DESC, &itemDesc,
                            ITEM_LINK, &itemLink, -1);

        // set item name
        gtk_entry_set_text (txtName, itemName);
        //gtk_label_set_text (txtDesc, itemDesc);
        // set item description

        txtBuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (txtDesc));
        gtk_text_buffer_set_text (txtBuffer, itemDesc, -1);
        // set item link
        gtk_entry_set_text(txtLink, itemLink);


        FREE_POINTER1 (itemName);
        FREE_POINTER1 (itemDesc);
        FREE_POINTER1 (itemLink);
    }
    else {
        gtk_entry_set_text (txtName, "");
        gtk_entry_set_text (txtLink, "");
        /*
        txtBuffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (txtDesc));
        gtk_text_buffer_set_text (txtBuffer, "", -1);
        */
        gtk_label_set_text (txtDesc, itemDesc);
    }
}

void
on_podcast_selection_change (GtkTreeSelection *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    GList        * selection  = gtk_tree_selection_get_selected_rows (widget, NULL);
    GtkTreePath  * tree_path  = NULL;
    char         * message    = NULL;
    GtkStatusbar * status_bar = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "status_bar"));
    guint          context    = gtk_statusbar_get_context_id (status_bar, "some_context_id");
    kpodcastPtr    podcast    = NULL;
    GtkListStore * liststore  = NULL;
    GtkTreeIter    iter;
    guint          item_list_length = 0, jj=0;

    if (selection) {
        tree_path = (GtkTreePath *) selection->data;
        int depth = gtk_tree_path_get_depth (tree_path);

        if (depth == 1) { // replace by assert (depth = 1)
            //set GtkTreeIter to index
            // Add Name and Description to the UI
            //
            int * idx = gtk_tree_path_get_indices (tree_path);
            podcast = (kpodcastPtr) g_list_nth_data (all_podcasts, *idx);
            /*
            gtk_entry_set_text(txtName, podcast->name);
            txtBuffer = gtk_text_buffer_new (NULL);
            gtk_text_buffer_set_text (txtBuffer, podcast->desc, -1);
            gtk_text_view_set_buffer(txtDesc, txtBuffer);
            */

            //
            // Get list store
            //
            liststore = GTK_LIST_STORE (gtk_builder_get_object (builder,  "liststore_podcast_items"));
            gtk_list_store_clear (liststore);

            //
            // Add all podcasts
            //
            item_list_length = g_list_length (podcast->items);
            for (jj=0; jj<item_list_length; jj++) {
                kpodcastItemPtr item = (kpodcastItemPtr) g_list_nth_data (podcast->items, jj);
                GDateTime * gDate = NULL;
                char * date;
                gDate = g_date_time_new_from_unix_local (item->pubDate);
                date = g_date_time_format (gDate, "%Y-%m-%d");
                gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &iter);
                gtk_list_store_set (liststore, &iter,
                                      ITEM_NAME, item->name,
                                      ITEM_DATE, date,
                                      ITEM_DESC, item->desc,
                                      PODCAST_IDX, *idx,
                                      ITEM_LINK, item->link,
                                      -1);
                g_date_time_unref (gDate);
            }

        }
    }
    else {
        message = g_strdup ("Treepath is NULL.");
        gtk_statusbar_push (status_bar, context, message);
        //g_printf ("statusbar push returned %d.\n", rc);
        g_free (message);
    }
    g_list_free_full (selection, (GDestroyNotify) gtk_tree_path_free);
}

void
on_action_add_podcast (GtkWidget * widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkStatusbar * status_bar = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "status_bar"));
    if (status_bar == NULL)
        printf ("No status bar.\n");
    else {
        guint context = gtk_statusbar_get_context_id (status_bar, "somectxt");
        char  * message = g_strdup ("add_podcast clicked.");
        guint   rc      = gtk_statusbar_push (status_bar, context, message);
        g_free (message);
    }
}

void
on_action_click_download (GtkWidget * widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkStatusbar * status_bar = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "status_bar"));
    if (status_bar == NULL)
        printf ("No status bar.\n");
    else {
        guint context = gtk_statusbar_get_context_id (status_bar, "somectxt");
        char  * message = g_strdup ("podcast download clicked.");
        guint   rc      = gtk_statusbar_push (status_bar, context, message);
        g_free (message);
    }
}

void on_button_test_clicked (GtkWidget * w, gpointer d)
{
    g_print ("on button test clicked!");
}

void quit (GtkWidget * w, gpointer d)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

#ifdef GTKUI
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
#else
int main_ (int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
{
    GError          * error = NULL;
    GtkWidget       * window;
    GtkListStore    * liststore_podcast;
    GtkTreeIter       iter;

    //
    // init the podcast stuff
    //

    // db
    if (!init_db ()) {
        printf ("DB could not be initialized: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg (db));
        return 0;
    }

    // timezone
    gTimeZone = g_time_zone_new_local ();

    // init podcasts
    if (!init_podcasts ()) {
        printf ("Podcasts could not be initialized, leaving.");
        return 0;
    }

    //
    // do the GTK+ stuff
    //
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    if (!gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "kaixN.glade", &error)) {
        g_warning ("%s", error->message);
        g_free (error);
        return 1;
    }
    liststore_podcast = GTK_LIST_STORE (gtk_builder_get_object (builder,  "liststore_podcasts"));
    if (liststore_podcast) {
        int ll = g_list_length (all_podcasts);
        if (ll == 0) {
            printf ("Podcast list is empty.\n");
        }
        else {
            int idx = 0;
            for (idx = 0; idx < ll; idx++) {
                kpodcastPtr podcast = (kpodcastPtr) g_list_nth_data (all_podcasts, idx);
                /* Append an empty row to the list store. Iter will point to the new row */
                gtk_list_store_append(liststore_podcast, &iter);
                gtk_list_store_set (liststore_podcast, &iter,
                                      PODCAST_NAME, podcast->name,
                                      -1);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        g_print ("Couldn't get liststore_podcasts.\n");
    }
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder,  "main_window"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks
Kai

Comment: It's not clear where exactly your code crashes -- could you add a backtrace? From a quick glance I notice you don't check `gtk_tree_model_get_iter()` return value.

Comment: Just installed libglib-2.0-dbg but how do I make use of it to get a full stack trace? I now check the return code of gtk_tree_model_get_iter() and this is not the problem.

Comment: If you don't need editing, then you can use `GtkLabel` to display the info instead of `GtkTextView`. Labels can display multiline text.

Comment: @kaidentity you should run the code in a debugger, e.g. gdb: install gdb, start it with `gdb <executablename>` and run the code with `r`, then do whatever you need to do to trigger the crash, then use `bt` to get the backtrace.

Comment: @jku: I created the stacktrace but since it's a stackoverflow it's pretty long. Accessible at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25030606/bt.txt.

Comment: @ptomato I tried that and it works but the border looks completely different than GtkEntry, it centers the text (I want it in the upper left corner)... The visual appearance was completely different. Can the label be customized to look like a GtkEntry?

Comment: If you want a border on the GtkLabel, put it inside a GtkFrame and customize it with CSS. To align the text to the upper left, set the `xalign` and `yalign` properties to 0 and the justification to left.

Comment: @jku I removed the scrolledwindow around the GtkTextEntry. Then it works. When I look at the stack trace it looks like the size negociation between the text entry and the scrolled window goes into an endless loop...

Comment: @kaidentity agreed. Do you happen to have any size allocation related code of your own? If not, it's starting to sound like a GTK+ bug.